# UISlider iOS with images for different levels

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

[image]

I 'm checking documentation `UISlider` for iOS. It has two image properties (one for minValueImage and another for maxValueImage). However, I like to develop a slider in my app, which shows different images (5 levels), as in 5 different images based on the slider selection. How can I accomplish this.

Any pointers or reference implementations will be very helpful.

Comment: can you share the visual of what you want?

Comment: please see the above. I updated the image, you can see.

Comment: Use UIImageView and UISlider to achieve this. Based on the value on the slider, update the image.

Answer (score 2):

By Using `UIImageView` and `UISlider` you can achieve this.

First of all set minimum value **1** and maximum value **5** to your `UISlider`

```
yourSlider.minimumValue = 1
yourSlider.maximumValue = 5
```

Based on the change value on the slider, update the image.

```
@IBAction func slider(_ sender: Any) {

    sender.value // Based on slider value change Update image from Here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a view on top of slider. The view should have same width as the slider.
You can add Five image views with equal widths and set the image at the center.
You can highlight the image based on the value of the slider.